# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget Wont Close

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am trying to use the jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget on my website, using the demo at http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic

I thought at first it was the way that I had coded it into my site, but after visiting the demo page in Firefox and Chrome it appears not to close in either of those either using the demo website.

If it really is buggy, can anyone recommend a multiselect jquery script that uses the jquery ui skin like the example above, but actually closes when you hit the close button ?.

Many Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the basic demo, which doesn't have any close or hide option.
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#animations
Here in the source of this example they are passing show and hide. Try this.

Answer (score 3):

That same demo has an example of open/close animations, and upon encountering the same bugs that you did (Chrome/Firefox won't close), when hide is specified, the close works as intended

If you don't want an animation, I would use:

```
$("#test-1").multiselect({
    hide: ["blind", 1]
});
```

the second value passed to hide is the duration of the animation.